# How to get DDL statements of tables of external datasets in GCP BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, datatables, ddl, external-tables

I am trying to take a clone of external dataset's tables using a script.
Before that I need to take out DDL statements of all tables and dataset.
In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, DDL column is NULL for every table.

How to proceed?

In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, DDL column is NULL for every table.
It should have populated DDL statments of table like other datasets do.

Comment: What's your permissions?